# How to Build H3DAPI with Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode6, x3dom

I want to build **H3D** and communication with **x3dom**,
so I try to use `CMake` bug always get this situation: **H3DUTIL was not found**.

Can you help me please?

H3D 2.3 source code:

http://www.h3dapi.org/modules/PDdownloads/viewcat.php?cid=14

**I have to find a solution:**
Make sure that your H3DAPI, HAPI, and H3DUtil source trees all have the same parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution for source tree same:**

just download all these packages and arrange them in same directory/folder.

**H3Dutil was not found:**

Make sure you have set H3DUTIL_LIBRARY/H3DUTIL_DEBUG_LIBRARY and H3DUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR to the correct file paths and directory paths in the CMake.
libs that you should direct to are H3DUtil_vc9.lib H3DUtil_vc9_d.lib and point your includes to H3DUtil/include directory.